# How would I use sscanf to accept zero as an input, but not non-numeric input?

Tags: c, command-line, scanf

In the below example, I want to be able to accept 0 as a numerator, but not a denominator. I also wish to exclude input of characters that are not numeric. I feel like I'm missing something very simple, or don't quite understand how to use sscanf.

```
    #include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

double numerator = 0.0;
double denominator = 0.0;
double result = 0.0;


if (argc == 3.0) {
    sscanf(argv[1],"%lf", &numerator);
    sscanf(argv[2],"%lf", &denominator);

    result = numerator / denominator;


    if (denominator == 0){
        printf("invalid input - divide by zero not allowed\n");
    }
    else if (numerator == 0){
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    else printf("%lf\n", result);


}




return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really check for valid values *before* you do the operation.

Comment: You might also be interested in checking e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). Pay close attention to what the function *returns*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to use the scanf family function to make shure that input is valid is to try to read *something* after the number and control that you only get one single value:

```
if (argc == 3) {
    char dummy[2];
    if (sscanf(argv[1],"%lf%1s", &numerator, dummy) != 1) {
       printf("%s is not a valid input\n", argv[1]);
       return 1;
    }
    ...
sscanf(argv[2],"%lf", &denominator);
```

`%1s` will only allow blank characters (mainly space or newline) after input